# Update points of a user in mysql database using php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to take a string username from my android app and use that username to add 5 points to that specific users account.

```
Example: 
My database now: user_id  name  username  password  points
                    1     test    test      test      0 

What I want:     user_id  name  username  password  points
                    1     test    test      test      5
```

Here is the php code I'm using right now, something must be wrong with it:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id177667_root", "***", "id177667_loginb");
$username = $_POST["username"];
$sql = "UPDATE user ". "SET points = points + 5 ". "WHERE username = $username" ;
$response = mysqli_query($sql, $con);
?>
```

Comment: too many errors in this. Do take the time to read the manuals

Comment: ^^ yheah but it will just be the user-name being a string so the query needs some quotes.

Comment: i do love this concatenation `". "`

Comment: @Dagon Yours looks like barbells.

Comment: @Lupinity don't modify code as per pending edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14351846

Comment: @Fred: just tried to at least eliminate the non-buggy confusing parts in order to focus on his real problem(s)... but ok.

Comment: @Lupinity edits are to correct typos in writing, tags, indenting but not to modify code.

Comment: @Fred: ok, sorry, I'm still new to this :P

Comment: @Lupinity and now you know ;-)

Comment: still not working, the uploaded version of the prepared statements if giving me a http error 500!

Comment: @gamer_central4: please use "add a comment" to add a comment, not edit :-)

Comment: ok, but the 5 points are not being added and the I'm getting a http error 500!

Comment: I updated my code with error handling for the prepare statement. You probably have a database error there. Try the new code and you'll see what fails.

Answer (score 3):

You confused the parameters for mysqli_query. It should be `mysqli_query($con, $sql);` instead. Also there are a couple of other problems - this should work:

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id177667_root", "***", "id177667_loginb");
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]);
  $sql = "UPDATE user SET points = points + 5 WHERE username = '$username'" ;
  $response = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
```

As it was suggested, prepared statements are the preferred way to go. So you could do this... tested it now, and it works for me:

```
<?php
  $points = 5;

  // Connect to database (credentials should not be stored in code...)
  $con = new mysqli("localhost", "id177667_root", "***", "id177667_loginb");

  // Check if connection succeeded
  if ($con->connect_error)
    die("Connection error: " . $con->connect_error);

  // Prepare statement
  if ($st = $con->prepare("UPDATE user SET points = points + ? WHERE username = ?")) {

    // Bind parameters (i for integer value, s for string)
    $st->bind_param("is", $points, $_POST["username"]);

    // Execute statement
    $st->execute();

    // Close statement
    $st->close();
 } else {
   // Prepare failed: report error
   die("Prepare failed: " . $con->error);
 }

  // Close DB connection
  $con->close();
?>
```

Comment: oh that toooooo

Comment: no, not quite, almost.

Comment: Did I miss another error? There are so many :D

Comment: you added an error

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters`

Comment: Oops, sorry :) Fixed. Been a loooong time since I used that hacky stuff. Spoiled by ORMs :P

Comment: yipeeeeeeeeeeeeeee, you win:-)

Comment: prepared statements are better. real_escape_string can still be vulnerable, *believe it or not.*

Comment: @Fred: I know, I know... but do you really think that's the OP's biggest problem here? ;-) But ok, I'll add a proper version in a minute...

Comment: @Fred-ii- i prefer not, my tin foil hat and i are perfectly safe in our cardboard box with our escaped strings. the strings are real too

Comment: that's up to you, I'm just saying

Comment: OK, created a table, tested it, and it works for me :-)